# actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS event not being sent on Production version

Tags: actions-on-google

I have two actions that were recently deployed and were approved yesterday. These actions should play from a playlists. It is my understanding from the documentation (https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/rich-responses?hl=en#media_responses) I can use actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS to get the status ('status': 'FINISHED') before the track playback is nearing the end, to queue up the next track.

Unfortunately, I don't see this event firing in production. When I test in the Google actions console, and on my test device the event is sent without issue. Is there something I am missing in my production release?

Comment: You mean that you're not getting the media `FINISHED` state?

Comment: @NickFelker yes, that is correct